# How to get domain system environment variable(env) programatically using spring mvc(uat, stage)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to load the properties file automatically based on the server environment like stage, uat, qa etc programmatic way using spring 4. I tried two way

1. Setup system environment variable: env=local, dev, qa, uat.
2. Active profile: Spring option

However, this is not automatically detect the domain system environment variable. We have configure manually in the system.

Please can anyone help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overlay default spring config. Assuming you are working with spring-boot and have fat executable jar, you can override internal config file properties with external with command line params as follow

```
java -jar your-executable-fat-jar.jar --spring.config.name=external-prop-file-name --spring.config.location=classpath:/application.yml,file://<external-config-file-parent-dir-path-NOT-EXTERNAL-CONFIG-FILE-PATH>
```

where

```
spring.config.name - external config file name
spring.config.location - Locations to look for configuration files.
```

`spring.config.location` could be named to your env. So you will have separate directory for each env containing env specific configurations.

Final command may look like:

`java -jar app.jar --spring.config.name=application.yml --spring.config.location=classpath:/application.yml,file:///app/config/$CURRENT_ENV`

Assuming your current env value is set in `CURRENT_ENV` and all env specific configs directories follow rule `/app/config/<env_name>`